# What does "<T> T get()" mean? (And is it useful?)

Tags: java, generics

This seems to be valid Java syntax:

```
<T> T get();
```

But what does it mean? And is it useful?

---

**CLARIFICATION FOR DOWNVOTERS**

I understand what it means when the `T` is used in the method parameters, like this:

```
T get(Class<T> clazz);
```

The return type is inferrable from the class that's passed in.

But when you have no parameters to say what type T is, what type is it?

Comment: This is a generic method returning a value of type `T`. The `<T>` in front of the method signature indicates that `T` is a type parameter specifically of this method, not of the class that owns it.

Comment: It's whatever the caller asks for, which means it either a) always throws, b) always returns null, c) it's an evil hack.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman So, essentially it leaves it to the caller to decide the type, i.e. it's basically type-unsafe. Is that correct? Is it ever useful?

Comment: @aetheria That's correct; no, it's not useful.  The return type should be `Object` and the caller should be writing an explicit cast.

Comment: Why is there a confusion? It means _the exact same_. You're not obligated to use `T` in your parameter list. And yes it can be useful, for example in Guava: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28%29

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why is it an evil hack? As Tom pointed out, it's very useful for removing boilerplate in Guava

Comment: @Louis What if you knew what type it was by calling a `boolean isString()` or `boolean isInt()` method, then having <T> get() would save you from having to do a cast wouldn't it?

Comment: @beirtipol there's a difference between `<T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList()` and `<T> T get()`.  (Though the first one is no longer really necessary as of Java 7.)

Comment: @aetheria you should be doing the cast explicitly even in that case.

Comment: Sorry this is starting to get into an extended conversation, but why? Isn't it adding extra code for no additional type-safety?

Comment: Louis could you maybe write a full answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what does it mean?

It means the language has a set of rules intended to be as simple as possible, and here they've been combined in a way that isn't very useful.

A generic method has type parameters. A type parameter can be used in the return type, in the argument list, in the method body. It can be used in any combination of those, including none at all.

For example, these signatures can both be useful:

```
<T> T foo( T t )  // The return type can be the type parameter
<T> List<T> ( )   // A type parameter does not have to be an argument
```

The case of `<T> T get()` uses the same rules, combined differently.

> And is it useful?

Not particularly. You haven't shown an implementation. @LouisWasserman notes in an insightful comment that an implementation would either have to *throw, return null, or be a hack*.

Here's an example hack. I don't consider it useful, because there's a simpler way to accomplish this. *Maybe* it would be useful if you were converting from C to Java, and wanted the code to stay as parallel as possible.

```
public static class Union {
    public Object o;
    public Union( Object value ) { o = value; }
    public Class<? extends Object> getType() { return o.getClass(); }
    public <T> T value() {
        return (T) o;   // <-- uses type parameter to cast
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Union union = new Union( "foo" );

    Class<?> valueType = union.getType();
    if ( valueType.equals( String.class )) {
        String s = union.value();     // <-- the call 
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is the type of the variable you are assigning the return-value to.

e.g.
If you have a method like this one:

```
public static <T> T getGenericNumber() {
    // the number-generator might return int, double, float etc. values
    return (T) numberGenerator.getANumber();
}
```

You can for instance assign the return value of the method directly to a double value - without a cast:

```
Double a = getGenericNumber();
```

So you have basically moved your cast from the declaration of the variable into the method.

This is potentially dangerous because you can easily produce cast-exceptions cause you could do things like this - and still being able to compile:

```
String s = getGenericNumber();
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do `String s = getGenericNumber()` if you've explicitly bounded it to `extends Number`. But I get your point.

Comment: yup, you're right - in this case you could assign in just to numbers - i'm gonna change it

Comment: `So you have basically moved your cast from the declaration of the variable into the method.` This is really clarifying

Answer (score 2):

It means shag-all really. The code below will compile, with warnings, and then barf. There's no good reason for typing the method without declaring/inferring what the type is at some point.

```
public class GenericExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String eejits = get();
        System.out.println(eejits);

        Integer knobends = get(); // Throws a ClassCastException.
    }

    private static <T> T get() {
        return (T) "I love to downvote without explaining why";
    }
}
```

to be more explicit, it's no better than doing this (except perhaps you only have to cast in one place)

```
public class GenericExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = (String) get();
        System.out.println(s);

        Integer i = (Integer) get();
    }

    private static Object get() {
        return "I really hope the caller expects a String, cos otherwise I'm going to downvote them";
    }
}
```